# AppleScript and shell script issue

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, script

I used to run a shell command with AppleScript for authentication to a radius server, this was running fine as I could specify a parameter for the password.

the shell process was updated and don't accept the password parameter anymore and have to be done separately (prompted by terminal), so in terminal its look like it

```
~mycommand authenticate -username 
~password
```

unless I'm wrong "do shell script"m run in different instance so it's no point doing

```
do shell script + auth command
do shell script + password
```

is they anyway I can still use AppleScript and somehow let AppleScript answer with the password?

Comment: If there is no way to pass the _password_ with the initial _command_, then you will need to _script_ either **Terminal** or **iTerm**, the latter being more **AppleScript** scriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* shows an example of how it could be coded for [**iTerm2**](https://iterm2.com/index.html).

```applescript
set myPassword to text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Enter Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer)

tell application "iTerm"
    set myWindow to (create window with default profile)
    tell myWindow to tell the current session
        write text "echo mycommand authenticate -username"
        delay 1
        write text "echo " & myPassword
        delay 1
    end tell
    close myWindow
end tell
```

---

**Notes**:

As coded, it uses `echo` just for testing purposes, obviously you'd remove `echo` and `"echo " &`  for production run.

The `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted, or may not be necessary at all.  Test with the actual commands to see.